# How to create checkboxs that fetch from database and pass on value

Tags: php, arraylist, checkbox

I am new to php and can not turn a row into a checkbox field that passes onto a separate page.

---

```
if ($result = $db->query($sql) ) {


        //*start of original
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            ?>
            <!-- <form action="Confirmation.php" method="post"> -->
            <form action="Payment.php" method="post">
            <label for="PatientID">Choose the Patient you wish to register for:</label>
            <select name="PatientID" id="">
                <option value="" disabled>Please select a patient to enroll:</option>
                <!-- <option value="All">All Patients</option> -->
            <?php
            while($result = fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$row['PatientID']}'>" . $row['PatientName'] . '</br>';
            }


            //
            //while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>
                    //<option value="<?=$row['PatientID'];?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?=$row['PatientName']?></option>
            //*/        <?php
            //}
            echo '</select><input type= "submit" class="myButton" name="submit" value="Register Now" /></form>';
        } else {
            echo "There are no patients currently available for registration." ;
            $rosterListFail = true;
        }
} else {
    $message = $db->error;
    // echo $message;
}
//*/
//}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check them as in `checked="checked"` - it's unclear what the question is.

Comment: I am trying to use php to pull a field and turn it for a row display to a checkbox where a user and check the box, the user then selects "Register Now" button and it would push them to the next field of collecting a payment

Comment: `echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$row['PatientID']}' checked='checked' >" . $row['PatientName'] . '</br>';` - now it's checked....